# Show an object with three js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

Hello i just want to show an object with three js without webcam and marker juste a blank background and the object 
I try to pick some part of code from the damage helmet example but nothing work :/ I just want a simple thing.

For now i have this code:

```
function start(){

    var renderer    = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias : true,
        alpha: true
    });
    //renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color('lightgrey'), 0)
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute'
    renderer.domElement.style.top = '0px'
    renderer.domElement.style.left = '0px'
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // array of functions for the rendering loop
    var onRenderFcts = [];

    // init scene
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Create a camera
    var camera = new THREE.Camera();
    scene.add(camera);

    // Create a light
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    light.position.set(0, 0, 1);
    scene.add(light);


    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

    var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();

    mtlLoader.load( "3d_models/OBJ/ano/ano.mtl", function( materials ) {
        materials.preload();
        var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
        objLoader.load("3d_models/OBJ/ano/ano.obj", function ( object ) {
            object.rotation.set(-Math.PI/2,0,0);
            console.log(object.children[0])
            scene.add( object );
        });
    },
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( 'OBJ ' + ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
    },
    function ( error ) {
        console.log(error);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a example of code that's work i found it on three js example and I modify some line of code to simplify it:

```
var renderer;
        var clock = new THREE.Clock();
        var mixers = [];
        var onRenderFcts = [];
        var camera2, scene2;
        init2();

        function init2() {
            var container, stats;

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );
            camera2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera2.position.z = 250;

            scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.4 );
            scene2.add( ambientLight );
            var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
            camera2.add( pointLight );
            scene2.add( camera2 );

            var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

            var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();

            mtlLoader.load( "3d_models/OBJ/ano/ano.mtl", function( materials ) {
                materials.preload();
                console.log(materials);
                var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                objLoader.load("3d_models/OBJ/ano/ano.obj", function ( object ) {
                    console.log(object.children[0])
                    scene2.add( object );
                    onRenderFcts.push(function(){
                                object.rotation.y += 0.03;
                    })
                });
            },
            function ( xhr ) {
                console.log( 'OBJ ' + ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
            },
            function ( error ) {
                console.log(error);
            });
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        }

        onRenderFcts.push(function(){
                renderer.render( scene2, camera2 );
            })
        // run the rendering loop
        var lastTimeMsec= null
        requestAnimationFrame(function animate(nowMsec){
            // keep looping
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            if ( mixers.length > 0 ) {
                for ( var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i ++ ) {
                    mixers[ i ].update( clock.getDelta() );
                }
            }
            // measure time
            lastTimeMsec    = lastTimeMsec || nowMsec-1000/60
            var deltaMsec   = Math.min(200, nowMsec - lastTimeMsec)
            lastTimeMsec    = nowMsec
            // call each update function
            onRenderFcts.forEach(function(onRenderFct){

                onRenderFct(deltaMsec/1000, nowMsec/1000)
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not positioning your camera, so it might be inside your objects.

Also without seeing the rest of your code.. it's not obvious where you are calling "start()" from ?

Comment: <body onload="start()">
 
</body>
and i add this camera.position.set(0,0,0 ); and it still doesn't work, i also precise something: there is no error in the console

Comment: Right. if you do camera.position.set(0,0,0) it will probably be starting the camera inside your model. Try something like camera.position.set(0,0,-10) or something... Also.. use the Chrome debugger and place breakpoints inside each of those loaders and make sure the callbacks are getting called.. If that doesn't help.. post a fiddle, or your model, and we can try to debug it for ya.

Comment: camera.position.set(-10,-10,-10 ); doesn't work camera.position.set(0,0,-10 ); too i even tried with -100 :/

Comment: if i understood I have to place some console.log in each loader ?

Comment: I mean use the built in chrome debugger to step through the code and place breakpoints to see if things are getting called.. Check out this link..
https://medium.com/frontmen/art-of-debugging-with-chrome-devtools-ab7b5fd8e0b4

If you like, you can also join this slack channel and we may be able to help you: https://join.slack.com/t/threejs/shared_invite/enQtMzYxMzczODM2OTgxLWE5OTU4OTYxZTZlODk1ZGNjODIyMDZlODM4ZmUyMzNiOWIxMmFjNTYwOTc4MjU0ZmNiODk5MzZiMGJhMTkzZWI